# YUI3 Y.Panel - How to hide HTML contents while page is loading?

Tags: css, yui, yui3

I have a Panel that I'm using as a modal dialog box, and as such the contents should be hidden from view while the page is loading.  However, if I use CSS to set the div's `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` then the YUI `show()` & `hide()` methods don't work properly (eg, clicking the button to call up the modal dialog greys out the screen, but the referenced div does not appear).  Can anyone point me towards the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `yui3-widget-loading` to the container `div`.  When Y.Panel is instantiated, it will remove this class.  You can then define `.yui3-widget-loading { display:none; }` so it is not visible during page load.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks!  I knew it had to be something simple and built in that I was just ignorant of.  Source for this infonugget can be found here: https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/widget/